# Second mod rewrite rule not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 rules, the first one works, the second one does not.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^state/([a-zA-Z]*)/?$ state.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^cg/([A-Za-z0-9-_\+]+)/?$ cg.php?c=$1 [NC,L]
```

The first rule is: state/texas and it works.

The second is `cg/some_campground_here` and it doesn't work. I know its something simple, but I have searched for answers and so far, nothing has worked.

Any guidance is much appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure multiviews is turned off. If it's turned on (which on some installations it is by default), mod_negotiation will circumvent your rewrite rules. In the `Options` line try adding multiviews so it looks like:

```
Options -Indexes -Multiviews
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with yours rules, I tested it my apache mod_rewrite debugger tools(with a real apache server), and it's fine:

[image]

Maybe problem in your browser's cache? Or in something else, but not in yours RewriteRules.

Comment: I tested it as well and it works.. wonder if its my local apache server causing the issue. its making development slow down because I can't test it

Comment: Most likely a problem on your browser - he is caches requests.